# why can't I initialize a linked list like this?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

LinkedList.c

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"


struct ListNode
{
    int val;
    struct ListNode *next;
};

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    struct ListNode *head = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    head->next = NULL;
    struct ListNode *rear = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        struct ListNode s;
        s.val = a[i];
        s.next = rear->next;
        rear->next = &s;
        rear = &s;
    }
    struct ListNode *tmp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(tmp);


    //display
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",(*head).val);
        head = head->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I change the sentece  "struct ListNode s;" to "struct ListNode *s=malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));" and use "->" but not ".", it will work.

Comment: Inside the loop where you add nodes, you have `struct ListNode s;`. That defines `s` as a ***local*** variable, inside the loop. Each iteration the life-time of `s` ends, and at the start of next iteration a brand new `s` is created. Any pointers to that variable will become invalid once its life-time ends. You need dynamic allocation for the nodes you add as well (which just about any decent book, tutorial or class should have mentioned or at least shown).

Comment: thanks for response. I don't know whether my understanding is right: a local variable will be automatically freed kind of like using free() function. So when a local variable is inside a loop, it will be destroyed outside the loop. But if i use 'malloc()', it will  be valid untill I use 'free()'.

Comment: The *life-time* of data you allocate of the heap (using `malloc`) never ends, it's indeed valid until you pass the pointer to it to `free`.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, you're facing this because `ListNode` you create in your list creation loop is a local variable limited to loop scope. It only exists in that scope(for that particular iteration). You should use `malloc` for allocating `ListNode` and use `free` to de-allocate memory for your nodes when you're done with using the list. I did minor changes to your list creation loop:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    struct ListNode *s = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    s->val = a[i];
    s->next = rear->next;
    rear->next = s;
    rear = s;
}
```

When I ran this, I was able to see expected results:

```
src : $ gcc initializelinkedlist.c 
src : $ ./a.out 
1 2 3
```